# How to upload multiple files in wordpress without using any plugin

Tags: wordpress, image-uploading

How can I upload multiple files without using any plugin in my custom page?

Comment: you can easily get reference from here...https://vrajeshdave.wordpress.com/?s=upload

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
if (isset($_FILES['upload_image']))
{
    foreach($_FILES['upload_image']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name)
    {
            $file_name = $key.$_FILES['upload_image']['name'][$key];
            $file_size =$_FILES['upload_image']['size'][$key];
            $file_tmp =$_FILES['upload_image']['tmp_name'][$key];
            $file_type=$_FILES['upload_image']['type'][$key];  


                $uploadedfile = $file_name ;
                $upload_name = $file_name;
                $uploads = wp_upload_dir();
                $filepath = $uploads['path'] . ” / $upload_name”;
                if (!function_exists('wp_handle_upload'))
                {
                        require_once (ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
                }

                require_once (ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

                $upload_overrides = array(
                'test_form' => false
                );  

                $movefile = wp_handle_upload($uploadedfile, $upload_overrides); 

                if ($movefile && !isset($movefile['error']))
                {
                    $file = $movefile['file'];
                    $url = $movefile['url'];
                    $type = $movefile['type'];

                    // media_handle_upload( $file_handler, 0 );

                    $attachment = array(
                    'post_mime_type' => $type,
                    'post_title' => $upload_name,
                    'post_content' => 'Image for ' . $upload_name,
                    'post_status' => 'inherit',
                    'post_parent' => $post->ID
                    //'post_parent' => 0 //IF DONT WANT TO ATTACH POST ID
                    );
                    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $file, $post->ID);
                    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $file, 0);//IF DONT WANT TO ATTACH POST ID

                    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $file);
                    wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attach_data);

                    echo $postid = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
                }

        }

}
```

> Dont forgot to add **`enctype="multipart/form-data"`** in form tag